# set dragable false for particular div in angular js with ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is used for match the following option.
While I drag the div id 'div2' along with this first div id 'div1' also to be dragged. how to set draggable false for div id 'div1'

---

```
.controller('BEGINNER_UNIT_1_CONVERSATION_ACTIVITY_2', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) 
{   
    $scope.OnDropComplete = function (index, source) 
    {
        var otherObj = $scope.category_Question[index];
        var otherIndex = $scope.category_Question.indexOf(source);
        $scope.category_Question[index] = source;
        $scope.category_Question[otherIndex] = otherObj;
    }         
})    
--------------------------------------------------------
<div ng-repeat="source in category_Question" ng-controller="BEGINNER_UNIT_1_CONVERSATION_ACTIVITY_2"  >
      <div class="card" id="div1" draggable="false">
        <div class="item item-divider">{{ $index+1 }}.Sentence </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="color:#CC0066;font-weight:bold;">{{ source.Sentance }}</div>
      </div>      
      <div class="card" id="div2" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="OnDropComplete($index,$data)">
        <div ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="source" ng-class="source.Response">
      <div class="item item-divider">Response</div>
      <div class="item item-text-wrap"> {{ source.Response }} </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong attribute. `draggable="false"`.

It should be `ng-cancel-drag`

Your html would look like:

```
<div class="card" id="div1" ng-cancel-drag>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I changed into ng-draggable="false" but not working. both the div's are swaped.

Comment: Hi Gowri, I used the wrong code. You should use `ng-cancel-drag="true"`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Which drag/drop module are you using?

Comment: ngDraggable (ngDraggable.js)

Comment: And what happens if you just use `ng-cancel-drag` (without true/false)?
To be clear: you're using this one?: https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable

Comment: <div ng-repeat="source in category_Question"  ng-controller="BEGINNER_UNIT_1_CONVERSATION_ACTIVITY_2">
<div class="card" id="div1" ng-cancel-drag="false">
<div class="item item-divider">{{ $index+1 }}.Sentence </div>
 <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="color:#CC0066;font-weight:bold;">{{ source.Sentance }}</div>
      </div>      
   ---I used both true and false but not woking